# Virtuoso 7 crashes while bulk loading

Tags: freebase, virtuoso

I am trying to create a local SPARQL endpoint for Freebase for running some local experiments. While using Virtuoso 7, I regularly see server getting killed by OOM killer. I have followed all the required steps as mentioned [here](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader). I have also made the required changes to my `virtuoso.ini` file as mentioned in [RDF Performance Tuning](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning).

My system configuration is:

- 8 CPU 2.9 Ghz
- 16 GB RAM

I have enough hard disk too.

Regarding data dumps, I have split the freebase data dump (23GB gzipped, approx 250 GB uncompressed) into 10 smaller gzipped files containing 200,000,000 triples each.

Following are the changes I made to `virtuoso.ini`

```
NumberOfBuffers = 1360000
MaxDirtyBuffers = 1000000

MaxCheckpointRemap = 340000  # (1/4th of NumberOfBuffers)
```

Along with this I have set `vm.swapiness = 10` as mentioned in [2](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning).

Am I missing something obvious?

P.S.:
I did try `virtuoso-opensource-6.1` too. But it appeared to be too slow.

One interesting observation I had was that during bulk loading process, virtuoso-6.1 memory consumption was rising too slowly, but it might be because general indexing itself was too slow.

Another observation I had was the virtuoso-6.1 at start time occupies almost negligible memory (order of 500MB) whereas virtuoso-7 starts with approx 6500 MB and grows quickly.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Exact version of Virtuoso is important -- usually best is output of `virtuoso-t -?` adjusted for your local binary filename. Are you using the [built-in Bulk Load features](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader) as recommended? With 16GB of total memory, you probably have 10-14 GB free memory -- and this is what should [inform your tuning settings](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning#How%20to%20determine%20available%20Memory).

Comment: Note that [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)-specific questions are often answered more quickly via focused channels such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso.)

Answer (score 1):

Numbers of buffers you are using is little bit too high. Do not forget that some memory is also consume by OS and other processes.

Which exact version do you use? (development or stable branch?)

Do you use disk striping ?

I load freebase to Virtuoso 7 too, but I used smaller files. Circa 260 gzipped files, 10mil triples each = circa 100M. A commit is executed after every file load.

Maybe would be easier for you to use [images with Virtuoso preloaded by Freebase](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sindicetech-freebase)